# How could I make this KD-tree?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, tree, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a very long, semi-sorted list of latitude, longitude, and time zone triplets. I want to be able to search this list quickly to find the closest time zone to any given latitude and longitude, so I would like to make this list into a KD tree.

I'm thinking that I should read the entire file first into some sort of data structure (what data structure? Possibly `ArrayList<Triplet<Double, Double, String>>`?). Then take the median element in that structure and make it the root, leaving me with a left and right list. Then keep taking the median element of each list and adding it as a left or right child.

A first attempt at this seemed slow and inefficient... But I feel like I did it wrong. Can you provide me with an algorithm or pseudocode for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions on the KDTree. If it is still slow/inefficient, let me know; I am curious!

Comment: I compared your implementation to the KDTree-implementation in Java-ML (http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/), and yours is much slower in extracting k nearest neighbours. Your interface is nicer though :)

Comment: Also, here are some even faster implementations: http://robowiki.net/wiki/Kd-tree#Implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, I have a [KD-Tree in Java](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/KdTree.java) which takes in XYZ as doubles in a inner class called XYZPoint. You could augment the XYZ Point with the time zone data and use X for Longitude, Y for Latitude, and zero for Z. It could at least be a starting point.

You could then use a nearest neighbor (euclidean distance) method, which is already implemented, for the closest time zone to a point.

Also.. for populating the KD-Tree, [wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Balancing) suggests using [HeapSort (my Java implementation linked)](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/sorts/HeapSort.java) and removing the median repeatedly.